# Managing task cancellation and completion on a concurrent thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

[ This question needs to be reimagined.  One of my thread queues MUST run on an STA thread, and the code below does not accommodate that.  In particular it seems Task<> chooses its own thread and that just is not going to work for me. ]

I have a task queue (BlockingCollection) that I'm running through on a dedicated thread.  That queue receives a series of Task<> objects that it runs sequentially within that thread via a while loop.

I need a means of Cancelling that series of tasks, and a means of knowing that the tasks are all complete.  I have not been able to figure out how to do this.

Here's a fragment of my queuing class.  ProcessQueue is run on a separate thread from main.  QueueJob calls occur on the main thread.

```
using Job = Tuple<Task<bool>, string>;
public class JobProcessor
{
  private readonly BlockingCollection<Job> m_queue = new BlockingCollection<Job>();
  volatile bool cancel_queue = false;
  private bool ProcessQueue()
  {
     while (true)
     {
        if (m_queue.IsAddingCompleted)
           break;
        Job tuple;
        if (!m_queue.TryTake(out tuple, Timeout.Infinite))
           break;

        var task = tuple.Item1;
        var taskName = tuple.Item2;

        try
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Task {0}::{1} starting", this.name, taskName);
           task.RunSynchronously();
           Console.WriteLine("Task {0}::{1} completed", this.name, taskName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           string message = e.Message;
        }
        if (cancel_queue) // CANCEL BY ERASING TASKS AND NOT RUNNING.
        {
           while (m_queue.TryTake(out tuple))
           {
           }
        }
     } // while(true)

     return true;
  }

  public Task<bool> QueueJob(Func<bool> input)
  {
     var task = new Task<bool>(input);
     try
     {
        m_queue.Add(Tuple.Create(task, input.Method.Name));
     }
     catch (InvalidOperationException)
     {
        Task<bool> dummy = new Task<bool>(() => false);
        dummy.Start();
        return dummy;
     }
     return task;
  }
```

Here are the functions that trouble me:

```
  public void ClearQueue()
  {
     cancel_queue = true;
     // wait for queue to become empty.  HOW?
     cancel_queue = false;
  }
  public void WaitForCompletion()
  {
     // wait for all tasks to be completed.  
     // not sufficient to wait for empty queue because the last task
     // must also execute and finish.  HOW?
  }
}
```

Here is some usage:

```
class SomeClass
{
   void Test()
   {
      JobProcessor jp = new JobProcessor();
      // launch Processor loop on separate thread... code not shown.
      // send a bunch of jobs via QueueJob... code not show.
      // launch dialog... code not shown.
      if (dialog_result == Result.Cancel)
          jp.ClearQueue();
      if (dialog_result == Result.Proceed)
          jp.WaitForCompletion();
   }
}
```

The idea is after the work is completed or cancelled, new work may be posted.  In general though, new work may come in asynchronously.  WaitForCompletion might in fact be "when all work is done, inform the user and then do other stuff", so it doesn't strictly have to be a synchronous function call like above, but I can't figure how to make these happen.

(One further complication, I expect to have several queues that interact.  While I am careful to keep things parallelized in a way to prevent deadlocks, I am not confident what happens when cancellation is introduced into the mix, but this is probably beyond scope for this question.)

Comment: It would be really awesome to see the `code not shown` code so that we have a [mcve]. I'd like to suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this code as it will make it far far simpler, but I can't give you a good clear example without the rest of your code. I specifically need to see how you're loading up your work and what the work is that you're performing.

Comment: How hard is it to convert to the Reactive Framework?  I get what you're saying about MCVE.  I was hoping that wouldn't be necessary because I don't have simple code to do the things I omitted, only complex things.

Comment: Back to the drawing board.  I can't construct tasks in this fashion because some stuff needs to run on STA threads.

Comment: The Reactive Framework can be very simple - often it collapses a lot of code into just a few lines. It also includes a single thread scheduler that might be of use for you. Can you show the `code not shown` or even just a simplified (working) version?

Answer (score 0):

WaitForCompletion() sounds easy enough.  Create a semaphore or event, create a task whose only action is to signal the semaphore, queue up the task, wait on the semaphore.

When the thread finishes the last 'real' task, the semaphore task will be run and so the thread that called WaitForCompletion will become ready/running:)

Would not a similar approach work for cancellation?        Have a very high priority thread that you create/signal that drains the queue of all pending jobs, disposing them, queueing up the semaphore task and waiting for the 'last task done' signal?